# What is the difference between phrases "is used when" and "is used for when"?

Tags: differences, semantics, be

I was recently reading some articles about type conditionals, and [one of them](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) had a following line:

> The zero conditional is used for when the time being referred to is now or always and the situation is real and possible.

While I had been taking notes, I unconsciously wrote:

> #### The zero conditional
>
> is used when: ...

I am used to the phrase "[be] used when", which doesn't have that "for".

I suppose both options are grammatically correct, but **is there really any difference?**

Comment: That word "for" doesn't add anything.

Comment: *For* is used for expressing purpose or situation, but I agree it doesn't make much difference here, as you can also express purpose or circumstances just with *when*.

Comment: Imho non-native speaker *leearners* are much more likely than native Anglophones to include the superfluous preposition in this exact context. As [this chart shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+when%2Cused+for+when&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20when%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20for%20when%3B%2Cc0), native Anglophones almost *never* include it.

Comment: ...but as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=used+when+the%2Cused+for+when+the%2Cused+if+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cused%20when%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20for%20when%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20if%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cused%20when%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20for%20when%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cused%20if%20the%3B%2Cc0) shows, we often use ***if*** instead of ***when***. Offhand I can't think of any contexts where the meaning depends on whether it's ***if*** or ***when***, or whether or not ***for*** is present.

Comment: Minimal difference. Here,  'for when' = 'when' = 'where' = 'in [those] situations where'.

Comment: The time being referred to is now. Forks are used for eating. Forks are used when eating.

Comment: @Lambie it's not the same, the aforementioned article uses phrase "[be] used for when" and you miss that when.
Overall, now I feel as if this construction was brought to English from some other language, like: "Use it in good health", which is used by some Italians. Because if you look at the very first chart, it shows that in 1800 this phrase hadn't even been used.

Comment: It's just an unedited oversight but it is not wrong.

Comment: whatserface: It's very unlikely mainstream English preposition use would be significantly affected by other languages. Historically, hardly any native Anglophones would have interacted much with people speaking other languages anyway. But to the extent that ***words*** are sometimes transferred from one language to another, they will nearly always be ***content*** words *(nouns, verbs, adjectives)*, not ***function*** words *(prepositions, articles, etc.*) or ***syntax***.

Comment: IMO there is a difference in an example of a 'Code of Conduct' or 'Operational Procedures' being in place and already routinely used. They are used **for when** an emergency etc. situation arises. They are not used **when** the situation arises: because they are already being used, and are perhaps only *necessary* when the event occurred, and help to prevent the situation being worse.

Comment: It seems to be conflating two phrases used to describe the situational function of something. One is _X is used when Y happens_, with no _for_; and the other is _X is for when Y happens_, with no _used_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm a little confused about: "They are not used **when** the situation arises: because they are already being used, and are perhaps only *necessary* when the event occurred, and help to prevent the situation being worse", - what does it have to do with conditionals? Subject has: "The zero conditional is used for when the time being referred to is now or always and the situation is real and possible", - can it somehow help to prevent the sentence being worse, while already being used? That's absurd, if conditional is already used then it can't make any more impact on the sentence.

Comment: @whatserface I'm a little confused about "conditionals"; I didn't mention them, so I don't know what you're referring to. I just noticed that the ungrammatical *_X is used for when Y_ is a conflation of two phrases with similar meanings, and thus probly represents a typo. Instead of some fussy grammatical point. Clearly any source speaking about numbered conditionals is full of it to start with, so sloppy syntax is no surprise.

Comment: @JohnLawler oh yeah, I see now, you weren't talking specifically about conditionals.
Also, thank you for the last enlightenment :D